# Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:2.12.4:test

Tags: xml, maven, dependencies, integration-testing, wso2-esb

I am developing a WSO2 ESB connector. When I am testing it with testng framework I got the following error.

Running TestSuite
    [2014-09-15 17:06:14,571]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.automation.core.PlatformExecutionManager} -  ---------------Test Execution Started --------------------------
    [2014-09-15 17:06:14,574]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.automation.core.PlatformExecutionManager} -  Uploading Services to App Server...
    [2014-09-15 17:06:14,577]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.automation.core.UserPopulator} -  Populating Users....
    [2014-09-15 17:06:14,580] ERROR {org.wso2.carbon.automation.core.utils.UserListCsvReader} -  User list not foundjava.io.FileNotFoundException: /home/dinithi/Desktop/toodledo[final]/ToodleDo/src/test/resources/userList.csv (No such file or directory)
    [2014-09-15 17:06:14,580] ERROR {org.wso2.carbon.automation.core.utils.UserListCsvReader} -  Configuration file not found
    org.apache.maven.surefire.util.SurefireReflectionException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException; nested exception is java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException: null
    java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
            at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
            at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
            at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
            at org.apache.maven.surefire.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethodWithArray(ReflectionUtils.java:189)
            at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ProviderFactory$ProviderProxy.invoke(ProviderFactory.java:165)
            at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ProviderFactory.invokeProvider(ProviderFactory.java:85)
            at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.runSuitesInProcess(ForkedBooter.java:115)
            at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.main(ForkedBooter.java:75)
    Caused by: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
            at org.wso2.carbon.automation.core.UserPopulator.populateUsers(UserPopulator.java:75)
            at org.wso2.carbon.automation.core.PlatformExecutionManager.onExecutionStart(PlatformExecutionManager.java:82)
            at org.testng.TestNG.runExecutionListeners(TestNG.java:1032)
            at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:983)
            at org.apache.maven.surefire.testng.TestNGExecutor.run(TestNGExecutor.java:178)
            at org.apache.maven.surefire.testng.TestNGXmlTestSuite.execute(TestNGXmlTestSuite.java:92)
            at org.apache.maven.surefire.testng.TestNGProvider.invoke(TestNGProvider.java:96)
            ... 9 more
    Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
            at org.wso2.carbon.automation.core.utils.UserListCsvReader.csvUserReader(UserListCsvReader.java:111)
            at org.wso2.carbon.automation.core.utils.UserListCsvReader.(UserListCsvReader.java:56)
            ... 16 more

What could be the error? and how to resolve it?

Thank you in advance.

And my pom.xml is as below.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!--suppress ALL -->
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.wso2.esb.connector</groupId>
    <artifactId>com.wso2.esb.connector</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0</version>
    <packaging>bundle</packaging>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.wso2.carbon</groupId>
            <artifactId>org.wso2.carbon.mediation.initializer</artifactId>
            <version>4.2.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.wso2.carbon</groupId>
            <artifactId>org.wso2.carbon.connector.core</artifactId>
            <version>4.2.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.synapse</groupId>
            <artifactId>synapse-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.2-wso2v4</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- test automation dependancies -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.wso2.carbon.automation</groupId>
            <artifactId>org.wso2.carbon.automation.engine</artifactId>
            <version>${automation.framework.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.wso2.carbon.automation</groupId>
            <artifactId>org.wso2.carbon.automation.core</artifactId>
            <version>${test.framework.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.wso2.carbon.automation</groupId>
            <artifactId>org.wso2.carbon.automation.test.utils</artifactId>
            <version>${automation.framework.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.wso2.carbon.automation</groupId>
            <artifactId>org.wso2.carbon.automation.extensions</artifactId>
            <version>${automation.framework.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.wso2.carbon</groupId>
            <artifactId>org.wso2.carbon.integration.common.extensions</artifactId>
            <version>${common.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.wso2.carbon</groupId>
            <artifactId>org.wso2.carbon.integration.common.admin.client</artifactId>
            <version>${common.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.wso2.carbon</groupId>
            <artifactId>org.wso2.carbon.mediation.library.stub</artifactId>
            <version>${stub.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
                    <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.wso2.carbon</groupId>
            <artifactId>org.wso2.carbon.proxyadmin.stub</artifactId>
            <version>${proxyadmin.stub.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.wso2.carbon</groupId>
            <artifactId>org.wso2.carbon.mediation.initializer</artifactId>
            <version>${stub.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.synapse</groupId>
            <artifactId>synapse-core</artifactId>
            <version>${synapse.core.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.wso2.carbon</groupId>
            <artifactId>org.wso2.carbon.mediation.configadmin.stub</artifactId>
            <version>${stub.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.wso2.carbon</groupId>
            <artifactId>org.wso2.carbon.mediation.library.stub</artifactId>
            <version>${carbon.platform.version}</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
                    <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.wso2.carbon</groupId>
            <artifactId>org.wso2.carbon.integration.framework</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- <dependency>
            <groupId>org.wso2.esb</groupId>
            <artifactId>service-samples</artifactId>
            <version>4.8.1</version>
        </dependency> -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-digester</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-digester</artifactId>
            <version>2.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.wso2.carbon.automation</groupId>
            <artifactId>org.wso2.carbon.automation.api</artifactId>
            <version>${test.framework.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.wso2.carbon.automation</groupId>
            <artifactId>org.wso2.carbon.automation.core</artifactId>
            <version>${test.framework.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.wso2.carbon.automation</groupId>
            <artifactId>org.wso2.carbon.automation.utils</artifactId>
            <version>${test.framework.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>groovy</groupId>
            <artifactId>groovy-all</artifactId>
            <version>1.1-rc-1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jruby</groupId>
            <artifactId>jruby-complete</artifactId>
            <version>1.3.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <!--dependency>
            <groupId>emma</groupId>
            <artifactId>emma</artifactId>
            <version>${emma.version}</version>
        </dependency-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
            <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
            <version>6.1.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.wso2.carbon</groupId>
            <artifactId>SecVerifier</artifactId>
            <version>${carbon.platform.version}</version>
            <type>aar</type>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.6</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.activemq</groupId>
            <artifactId>activemq-core</artifactId>
            <version>5.2.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.geronimo.specs</groupId>
            <artifactId>geronimo-j2ee-management_1.1_spec</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.geronimo.specs</groupId>
            <artifactId>geronimo-jms_1.1_spec</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>ca.uhn.hapi.wso2</groupId>
            <artifactId>hapi</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.0.wso2v1</version>
        </dependency>
        <!--dependency>
            <groupId>org.wso2.esb</groupId>
            <artifactId>org.wso2.carbon.esb.tests.ui</artifactId>
            <version>4.8.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
        </dependency-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.wso2.esb</groupId>
            <artifactId>org.wso2.carbon.esb.common</artifactId>
            <version>4.8.0</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.skyscreamer</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsonassert</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.3</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>
    <properties>
        <automation.framework.version>4.3.1-SNAPSHOT</automation.framework.version>
        <stub.version>4.2.0</stub.version>
        <synapse.core.version>2.1.1-wso2v7</synapse.core.version>
        <common.version>4.3.0-SNAPSHOT</common.version>
        <proxyadmin.stub.version>4.2.1</proxyadmin.stub.version>
        <test.framework.version>${carbon.platform.version}</test.framework.version>
        <carbon.platform.version>4.2.0</carbon.platform.version>
        <esb.version>4.8.1</esb.version>
    </properties>

</project>
```

Project location : https://github.com/dinithiviranga/Toodledo

Comment: It seems the file */home/dinithi/Desktop/toodledo[final]/ToodleDo/src/test/resources/userList.csv* wasn't found - are you sure this directory is correct? It looks a bit odd to have *[final]* in the directory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the package names. Hope you have a problem with the packages according to the project https://github.com/dinithiviranga/Toodledo